# GCP OS Patch management logging

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, patch

In GCP I have created a patching job in OS Patch management. It shows the status in OS patch management console if the patching job has succeeded or failed.
[image]

when I click on logs it redirects to log explorer, but I dont see any logs in log explorer
Can I know how to enable logs to see it in log explorer ?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the documentation section [Debugging a patch job](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/create-patch-job#debug-patch) and change `osconfig-log-level` to `debug` in [metadata value](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#custom)?

Answer (score 2):

There may be two reasons for the status to show inactive

1. The VM is in off state when the patch is deployed.
2. The OS config Agent is absent in the VM
   To check the is the agent is present or not use the below command where the instance is inactive

> sudo systemctl status google-osconfig-agent

if the status is or not found you should install the agent refer the [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os#:%7E:text=In%20your%20Google%20Cloud%20project%2C%20enable%20the%20Container%20Analysis%20API,for%20the%20OS%20Config%20agent) to install the agent.

Comment: 3. or the patch filter doesn't include the VM.